# Converting base64 token after decoding to jsonString

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to convert the json string to my respective pojo class. The json string is decoded version of base64 token.
The decoded values are

```
{"userId":"1234567890","userName": "John Doe", roles: ["admin","users"]}
```

I am using code `String jsonFormat=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(decoded);` where decoded is above string mentioned.

I am getting below error when I am trying to convert it into object using `objectmapper`

```
    objectMapper.readValue(jsonFormat, PtsbUser.class);
```

Error:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.ptsb.rbaccomponent.models.PtsbUser` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{userId:"1234567890",userName: "John Doe", roles: ["admin","users"]}')
     at [Source: (String)""{userId:\"1234567890\",userName: \"John Doe\", roles: [\"admin\",\"users\"]}\n     \n  \n    ""; line: 1, column: 1]
```

I have update the decoded string putting parenthesis in keys also. I am using https://www.base64encode.org/ for encoded base64 which is giving me token

```
eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiAiSm9obiBEb2UiLCByb2xlczogWyJhZG1pbiIsInVzZXJzIl19CiAgICAgCiAgCiAgICA=
```

I am using below util code to get my decoded string:

```
    Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
            String decripted=new String (decoded);
            return decripted
```

Comment: could you please add your PtsbUser.class in your question?

Comment: Also, better you could share your encoded base64 token

Comment: @MOnkey i have updated my question. Please let me know if you need any further information

Answer (score 1):

if data is bas64 encoded json string you can do like this:

```
objectMapper.readValue(Base64.getDecoder().decode(data),  PtsbUser.class);
```

but your original string **is not valid** json:

```
{userId:"1234567890",userName: "John Doe", roles: ["admin","users"]}
```

this is valid one:

```
{"userId":"1234567890","userName": "John Doe", "roles": ["admin","users"]}
```

> objectMapper.writeValueAsString Method that can be used to serialize any Java value as a String

`objectMapper.writeValueAsString(decoded);` is  not needed here 
as this method is for `java -> json` serialization and you already have json string to deserialize

Answer (score 1):

Your decoded string should be like this, in order to convert it back to your java object ( i.e `PtsbUser`).

```
"{\"userId\":\"1234567890\",\"userName\": \"John Doe\", \"roles\": [\"admin\",\"users\"]}";
```

But here as from error I could see your decoded json string is

```
"{userId:\"1234567890\",userName: \"John Doe\", roles: [\"admin\",\"users\"]}\n     \n  \n    "";
```

Here, I am not sure how you have decoded your json string, once your json string will be decoded correctly as shown above you can use the following code to convert it into PtsbUser object as follows,

```
 String decoded = "{\"userId\":\"1234567890\",\"userName\": \"John Doe\", \"roles\": [\"admin\",\"users\"]}";
 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 PtsbUser ptsbUser = objectMapper.readValue(decoded, PtsbUser.class);
 System.out.println(ptsbUser);
```

And also I am hoping your `PtsbUser.java` class will look something like this.

```
public class PtsbUser {

    String userId;
    String userName;
    List<String> roles;
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

This is the way to decode your String

```
String inputToDecode = "eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwidXNlck5hbWUiOiAiSm9obiBEb2UiLCByb2xlczogWyJhZG1pbiIsInVzZXJzIl19CiAgICAgCiAgCiAgICA=";
Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
String decodedString = new String(decoder.decode(inputToDecode ), "UTF-8");
return decodedString;
```

Comment: yeah i am using like that only but i have created a utility to get me the decoed value using byte[] decoded=Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded);
  String decripted=new String (decoded);
  return decripted; to get me the decoded string

Comment: @unknown, could you accept the answer, if it help you?

Answer (score 0):

You will not need this line as you already have it as string.

```
  String jsonFormat = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(decoded);
```

This will put a double quotes around your decoded string. This method used only when you are writing your string to an output/response.

You can directly use the decoded string in `readValue` method

```
objectMapper.readValue(decoded, PtsbUser.class);
```

And your JSON has issues. You can validate your JSON at https://jsonlint.com/

Here, you need to wrap your keys with double quotes to make it a valid JSON

```
{
  "userId": "1234567890",
  "userName": "John Doe",
  "roles": ["admin", "users"] 
}
```